# wake up screen without unlocking the lock-screen

Tags: android, android-wake-lock

I am wringing a default phone app, and I need to unlock the device once a new call is coming in. I have been trying to do it like this:

```
    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON |
                    PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, getPackageName() + ":Call");
    wakeLock.acquire();
```

And this is the definition I used in Manifest. My min API is 23

```
    <activity
        android:name=".call.CallActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:showForAllUsers="true" />
```

Note that `PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK` was deprecated in API 17 and `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` is suggested to be used instead, however with this setup my screen is not being waked, and when I turn it on manually, my activity is not shown on top of the lock screen as the flag in the manifest suggest.

From the [showForAllUsers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#showForAllUsers) docs:

> Specify that an Activity should be shown even if the
>   current/foreground user is different from the user of the Activity.
>   This will also force the
>   android.view.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED flag to be set for all
>   windows of this activity

So what is the proper way to do it in API 23? My goal is to wake up the device and show my activity but do not unlock the lock screen.

Comment: this could help you: https://cgarrido.me/2017/08/22/unlock-android-screen-programmatically/

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `android:showOnLockScreen="true"` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` for your activity:

```
<activity
    android:name=".call.CallActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:showOnLockScreen="true"
    android:showForAllUsers="true" />
```

Comment: Isn't FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED is the same as android:showOnLockScreen?

Comment: no it's not. you need to declare it in the `AndroidManifest.xml`